# How do I get the local player?

Tags: unity, mirror-networking

I'm using [Mirror](https://mirror-networking.com/) as UNet is deprecated.
How can I get the local player GameObject in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, the best method is using [NetworkClient](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/api/Mirror.NetworkClient.html#Mirror_NetworkClient_localPlayer) from Mirror:

```
using Mirror;
GameObject localPlayer = NetworkClient.localPlayer.gameObject;
```

---

*Note that the following is deprecated and shouldn't be used.*
The ClientScene class has a static [property called localPlayer](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/api/Mirror.ClientScene.html#Mirror_ClientScene_localPlayer) of type NetworkIdentity. All Components in Unity have `gameObject` as property which refers to the GameObject they're attached to.
So in order to get the localPlayer object you would do:

```
using Mirror;
GameObject localPlayer = ClientScene.localPlayer.gameObject;
```